# Add background image to html.div in Dash-plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I know how to add a background image to a plotly graph object, however, is it possible to add background image for html.Div or html.H1 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working example demonstrating how to add a `background-image` using inline styles.

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from pandas_datareader import data as web
from datetime import datetime as dt
import plotly.graph_objs as go

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1('Hello Dash', style={'background-image': 'url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/North_Star_-_invitation_background.png)'})
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```